python file import not working in Sublime
Trying to link Two files in Sublime:
main.py
import module

def main():
    module.greet("Linda")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This is the Main.py file")
    main()

and
module.py
def greet(name):
    print(f"Hello, {name}!")

if __name__== "__main__":
    print("This is the module.py file.")

Error Received:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'
How do I correct this? What am I doing wrong?

You need these files to be in the same directory.

It should be something such as from . import module. An example of an import from an existing plugin: https://github.com/facelessuser/HexViewer/blob/master/hex_viewer.py#L14

this error usually happens mostly because of python not being able to find the 'module.py' file. this usually happens when 'module.py' isn't in the same directory as 'main.py'. ensure that both files are in the same directory, and run the file again from a terminal. this should resolve the issue.

Forgot to add that both files are actually in the same directory.  I was trying to run inside Sublime with command+B (MacOs).  I will try from terminal and see if results are different.  Thanks.
